# When and how do I use the Ldvirtftn opcode?

Tags: c#, .net, cil, reflection.emit

The following example program is my trying to grasp the usage of the `ldvirtftn` opcode

You see the name suggests this is the opcode to use when loading a virtual function pointer on to the stack. In the example code, I'm creating a type with 2 static methods `Ldftn` and `Ldvirtftn`, both of these methods return an open delegate of `Base.Method()` the first function `Ldftn` uses the `ldftn` opcode, and works unexpectedly, as `Base.Method` is virtual. The second method uses `Ldvirtftn` and apparently created an invalid program.

What am I doing wrong? What is the purpose of this opcode?

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
    }
}

public class Child : Base
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AssemblyBuilder ab =AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Test"),AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
        ModuleBuilder mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("TestModule");
        TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType("TestType");
        MethodBuilder method = tb.DefineMethod("Ldftn",MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(Action<Base>), Type.EmptyTypes);
        var ilgen = method.GetILGenerator();
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldftn, typeof(Base).GetMethod("Method"));
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(Action<Base>).GetConstructors()[0]);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        method = tb.DefineMethod("Ldvirtftn", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(Action<Base>), Type.EmptyTypes);
        ilgen = method.GetILGenerator();
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldnull);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldvirtftn, typeof(Base).GetMethod("Method"));
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(Action<Base>).GetConstructors()[0]);
        ilgen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var type = tb.CreateType();
        var func = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Action<Base>>),tb.GetMethod("Ldftn")) as Func<Action<Base>>;
        var func2 = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Action<Base>>), tb.GetMethod("Ldvirtftn")) as Func<Action<Base>>;
        func()(new Child());
        func2()(new Child());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Here is what happens in the `ldftn` case. Your method creates a delegate that has:

   - no first argument (usually used only for static methods);
   - `Base.Method()` as the method (which is *not* static).

   You create this delegate as `Action<Base>`, which happens to have one parameter. When you call this delegate in this line:

   ```
   func()(new Child());
   ```

   the CLR uses the new `Child` instance as the “first argument”. Since the method you are calling is *not static*, the first argument becomes the `this` pointer. Thus, this call becomes equivalent to

   ```
   new Child().Method();
   ```

   and this causes a separate virtual-method dispatch *at invoke time* (not at ldftn time), so `Child.Method()` gets called. This is why it prints “Child” instead of the “Base” that you probably expected.
2. In the `ldvirtftn` case, you are getting an invalid program because you forgot that `ldvirtftn` requires an object reference on the stack while `ldftn` doesn’t.

You could try making the following changes to understand what’s going on:

- Instead of `null`, pass an actual instance of `Base` or `Child` to the delegate constructor, as is customary for non-static methods. You will find that it will then refuse to create the delegate because the number of parameters no longer match (`Action<Base>` requires one parameter, but `Method()` has none).
- Make the number of parameters match, either by changing `Action<Base>` to simply `Action`, or by making `Method()` accept a parameter. In both cases, you will probably quickly find that it does what you expect. In particular, you will find that the delegate created with `ldftn` will always call `Base.Method()` even if you created it with an instance of `Child`.

Comment: Actually the virtual dispatch was what I was after. I didn't know virtftn only worked while passing an instance, so am I suppose to send to go: ld instance,dup,ldvirtftn Method,newobj delegate ctor?

Comment: What's strange is that a single static `string -> int` function can be used to create both "static" `Func<string, int>` delegate and an "instance" `Func<int>` delegate. Just `ldnull`(or `ldstr`)+`ldftn`+`newobj` with either delegate type.